# Chainsaw maintenance: infrequent usage

Tags: tools

I bought a battery chainsaw to help with winter clean up. I don't expect to use it much during the other seasons so I'm wondering how to store it.

Leave the bar oil in or try to drain it?

How much should I worry about cleaning out the wood bits that have gotten into every crevice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store your battery chainsaw effectively during the off-seasons, consider the following:

Bar Oil: It's generally recommended to empty the bar oil reservoir before storing the chainsaw. Leaving oil in the reservoir might cause leakage or degradation over time, potentially leading to issues when you next use the chainsaw. Drain the oil according to the manufacturer's instructions.

Cleaning: While it's not necessary to meticulously clean every crevice after every use, it's good practice to remove excess wood bits and debris from the chainsaw after each session. This prevents buildup and potential damage to the components. A thorough cleaning before long-term storage is advisable to ensure that no residue or debris remains, which could lead to corrosion or other problems over time.

Answer (score 3):

Battery charge level as the maker suggests - many 50% or "40-60%" during long term storage for LiIon types, or perhaps you have other tools to keep the batteries active.

I wouldn't worry about draining the bar oil, but I'd expect some dripping, so you might reduce that by attempting to drain it as much as possible. Or just put it in/on something that will catch the drips.

Sawdust cleanup couldn't hurt, but is not usually critical unless it's being stored in an area that's also damp (which is a bad choice anyway...)

Most of what sticks to the saw is somewhat oily from chain oil so not very corrosive. I tend only to clean it out when changing the chain or flipping the bar. Hasn't caused any noticable problems. Now, if they are really in "every crevice" including whatever cooling air intake, that would not be good - both the gas and corded electric saws I have were well-enough thought out to keep that clear, so I'd expect no less of a battery saw, but if it's not keeping the chips away from the air intakes, those need to be cleaned.

Comment: I have an AEG electric chainsaw, and ever since new, if I leave the oil in it it leaks out, seemingly regardless of orientationj.  I've taken to draining it out.

Comment: If it's more than a bit of dripping (so it's draining the whole tank) that's a sensible approach. Presumably varies by the design of the oil delivery mechanism.